# In Angular, how to return an Observable with result and errors from a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable

I'm newbie in Angular.

I'm developing some authentication functions that runs async with an promise and do some stuff in the middle of this code.
Considering async, I believe the function should returns an Observable. But how to return an Observable and the result/errors of the promise?

```
   authentication.service.ts

    loginwithProvider(): <????> {
       this.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
          .then( result =>{
                          /* do some things, such as getting data and logging */

                          })
          .catch( (error) => {
                          /* receive the error of the provider, do some things, such as logging */
                          })

        return ?????  <---- I want to return result and errors of the provider in an Observable to the caller function
    }


login.component.ts

onLogin(){

  this.request = this.authenticationService.loginWithProvider().subscribe(
    (data) => {
         console.log("onlogin - then success");
         this.router.navigate(['/']);
    },
    (error) => {
           console.log(" onlogin - error ", error);
           show_error_to_user(error);  <---- error from loginWithProvider
    });

}
```

Comment: Is this with `angularfire2` by chance?

Comment: yes, authentication with angularfire2 version 4

Answer (score 0):

I found an way using ReplaySubject.
(learned from Lars Bilde video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdD2sy7r7Mk)

```
authentication.services.ts
loginWithProvider() : ReplaySubject<any>  {
    let resultSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then( result => {
        /* do some things, such as getting data and logging */
        console.log("result", result)
        resultSubject.next(result);
       // return result;
      }).catch( (error) => {
      /* receive the error of the provider, do some things, such as logging */
      console.log("error", error)
      resultSubject.error(error);

    })
    return resultSubject;
  }
```

and

```
login.component.ts

onlogin() {
      this.authenticationService.loginWithProvider()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
        console.log("onloginwithprovider - then success", data);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(" onloginwithprovider - error ", error)
        });
    }
```